# Secure method for software distribution

Tags: software-distribution

I work at a software development company, and one of our tasks is to distribute our software to our customers before deployment. We have a lot of software components that at built separately, so we end up with 5 or more packages - usually more, and some times up to several hundred files because we also need to distribute data sets from time to time. We would like to find a way to distribute these packages to the customers as easy as possible. Currently we are using Box which is OK, but uploading and downloading several hundred packages takes a while, so we would like a method that will automatically place the files at the customers site.

Ideally we would like to end up with a file structure on our build environment, where we could place folders like:

Customer1
Customer2
Customer3
etc.

and putting files into those folders would automatically end up at that particular customer. It could probably be done by Dropbox, but we cannot install that at the customers sites.

We expect to build something with that functionality ourselves, but are there any frameworks or anything so we don't have to start from scratch? It's important that the files actually end up at the customers sites, and not on a shared drive somewhere in the cloud, since some of the customers have really slow internet connection. We are running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your startup page with web based verification process. If the software is installed in particular MAC ID, then verify it first at your web portal, and create one file or a value in db to ensure it is verified. From the 2nd time the startup page will check for the verification key in db or the verification file. If it is available then it will open the software otherwise it should redirect the software to registration page.

Comment: It's not about installing software - it's pure file distribution.